can not modify build process heap size in idea 2023.3
i was building project
and stucked in parsing java,then build fail because of 'java: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded'
try to increase build process heap size,found that i cannot modify
i tried reopen project,failenter image description here

Close IDEA and check for any left-over Java processes, stop them if there are any.

I just added more space and it worked!!  not 1024 ,added to 2048 or 3096
